# Office 365 DLP Incident Reports

Tags: microsoft-office-365

can anyone tell me if there's a way to customize Incident Reports generated when a DLP policy is triggered in Office 365? Like if there's a way to add fields and other information to the IR email sent to administrators, aside from what is already available by default.

Comment: What did O365 support say?

Comment: Actually, 0365 support is like prepaid, consumable. I was trying to look for answers externally before I can ask them, if that will be fine here. Just trying if someone already had experienced this.

Comment: Understood. Serverfault should not be your first line of defense, though. If you are able to use vendor-specific support, try there first.